# Fetching X-GM-LABELS with objective-c (Gmail Labels)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, gmail, gmail-imap

My goal is to have a `NSArray` or `NSSet` with the labels that are attached to a specific Email in a Gmail account my app. My app mainly uses MailCore that doesn't support this feature so extending it would be a preferable way.
I've been at the google "API" website [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/imap_extensions#access_to_gmail_labels_x-gm-labels) that didn't helped much and also found [this](https://github.com/dinhviethoa/libetpan/blob/master/src/low-level/imap/xgmlabels.c) inside my libetpan library but even though I have an open `IMAP` session open with a gmail account I still can't translate this code and get Gmail labels for specified messages. Any code examples are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write methods in MailCore to wrap around the libetpan x-gm-labels extension. I've written the SORT extension in MailCore a few month ago. You can take a look at that :)

[Add IMAP SORT command support. Pull Request on MailCore](https://github.com/MailCore/MailCore/pull/89)